# Создание элементов управления на ViewPager

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Как создать элементы управления на конкретной странице ViewPager из другого Activity с последующим обращением к ним? Нашел только onCreate самой страницы. Где можно хранить ссылки на эти элементы?

Допустим, хочу при каком-то ивенте создать на 3 странице ViewPager'a 2 элемента Button, а по другому ивенту поменять на них текст. Как это реализовать? Заранее извиняюсь за нубство и благодарю за ответ.

Comment: Если вам нужно из одной Activity  передать какие то параметры(состояние) в другое Activity  в котором ViewPager исходя из этих  параметров будет выбирать какой контент внутри себя создавать - вы можете сделать это с помощью интентов, хотя вариантов еще может быть несколько, например Service, или статический класс в котором можно хранить состояние.

Comment: @KirillStoianov Спасибо за ответ на один из вопросов. Но осталось неясным то, как можно сохранить где-то список элементов данной страницы ViewPager? Если я добавлю на нее 3 кнопки, то что мне нужно сделать, чтобы я потом в любой момент мог удалить их?

Comment: @ahgpoung нужно что бы ViewPager брал список нужных элементов с какого то хранилища, то есть при наполнении его контентом он берет список нужных данных из другого места. Таким "местом" может быть База Данных, SharedPreferences,  класс (singleton) который содержит в себе список, либо класс со статическим списком.

Comment: @KirillStoianov получается, что нельзя просто хранить где-то ссылки на эти элементы для дальнейшего их использования? И вообще не совсем понятно, как добавить элемент на какую-то конкретную страницу.

Comment: Если вы о том что бы, что бы поместить куда то экземпляр уже существующей активити, а потом в нужный момент ее оттуда достать и отобразить - я к сожалению не знаю. А по-поводу как добавить на конкретную страницу контент во ViewPager  - то это делается в адаптере.

Comment: @KirillStoianov не совсем понимаю, как конкретно это сделать? Вот как  сейчас выглядит адаптер. https://codeshare.io/svcLT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот пример моего адаптера который я использую для ViewPager с табами.

**ViewPagerAdapter.java**

```
class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    private List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void removeFragment(int position) {
        if (!mFragmentList.isEmpty() && position < mFragmentList.size()) {
            mFragmentList.remove(position);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        // return mFragmentTitleList.get(position); to display icons + text
        // return null to display only the icon
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }
}
```

В активити я его использую так:

**MaiActivity.java**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    adapter.addFragment(new ContactsFragment(), "Contacts");
    adapter.addFragment(new CardFragment(), "Cards");

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
}

private void addTab() {
    adapter.addFragment(new TestFragment(), "test");
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab());

    tabLayout.getTabAt(tabLayout.getTabCount() - 1).setIcon(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.icon_contacts));
}

private void removeTab() {
    int position = tabLayout.getTabCount() - 1;
    if (position >= 0) {
        adapter.removeFragment(position);
        tabLayout.removeTabAt(position);
    }
```

Таким способом в `onCreate` создаются две страницы во ViewPager, после чего в методе addTab можно добавить следующую страницу в ViewPager и новую табу, а метод removeTab удаляет по одной странице и одной табе начиная с последней.

Обратите внимание что в адаптере используется `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`, это если вам надо добавлять и удалять динамически, если просто создать какое то количество при старте активити, а потом просто добавлять туда дополнительные, то можно использовать `FragmentPagerAdapter`.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но это не совсем то, что нужно. Хотя, безусловно, это поможет мне в продвижении. Хотелось бы, для начала, понять, как добавить элементы управления на уже существующий стол ViewPager (т.е. после onCreate), а потом при каком-то действии поменять их свойства (текст на них, например). В идеале, хотелось бы понять, как их можно еще удалять. Не уверен, что это вообще возможно, т.к. только недавно начал заниматься разработкой и не понимаю полностью работу столов ViewPager.

Comment: Похоже у вас вопросов больше чем один) Можете их разделить и задать новые вопросы.